# Apache Camel Exchange Object is having truncated response

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-core

While we are upgrading to spring boot 2.7.1 and camel version to 3.14.6 , one of the rest api is retruning partial response.

But when I am directly invoking third party api we are getting complete response.

we are tried all the possibilities and we are expecting third party api should return complete response when we are invoking through apache camel.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, please provide some code to show what you tried. Please also read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried newer versions of Apache camel like 3.14.7? You could also use something like Mockoon to check how Camels http-component is calling the API. Request could be missing some headers or query-parameters required by the API resulting in partial response.